# Order data by data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

rooms (all the rooms)

```
id | title  | ...
-----------------
1  |Room 1  |
2  |Room 2  |
3  |Room 3  |
```

user_rooms (in which room is every user, column user is user's id and it's primary column)

```
user  | room | ...
------------------
20    | 3    |
14    | 1    |
35    | 3    |
```

So I want to select all the rooms from the 'rooms' table but to order them in that way to show the rooms with the most users in them and after that the rooms with less and less users. For example, I want to show room 3 first (because 2 users are in it), then room 1 (one user in it), and finally room 2 (since no users are in it). How to achieve that?

Comment: How do we know how many users there are in a room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select r.id, r.title, coalesce(t.cnt,0)
from rooms r left join
(select room, count(*) as cnt
from user_rooms
group by room) t on t.room = r.id
order by t.cnt desc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT aa.id, aa.title
FROM rooms AS aa
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT room, COUNT(*) AS total_count
    FROM user_rooms
    GROUP BY room
) AS _aa
ON aa.id = _aa.room
ORDER BY _aa.total_count;
```

Answer (score 2):

This would often be done without a subquery:

```
select r.id, r.title, count(ur.room) as numusers
from rooms r left join
     user_rooms ur
     on r.id = ur.room
group by r.id, r.title
order by numusers desc;
```

This would often be more efficient than a version using a subquery in the `from` clause because it can take advantage of an index on the join key.

Interestingly, the same index would be used for a correlated subquery in the `select`, which is an alternative approach:

```
select r.id, r.title,
       (select count(*)
        from user_rooms ur
        where r.id = ur.room
       ) as numusers
from rooms r
order by numusers desc;
```

This might be the most efficient approach, because it removes the aggregation in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you only rooms with users

```
    SELECT title, count(user) As MostUsers
    FROM Rooms R
    INNER JOIN user_rooms U
    ON R.?field? = U.?field?
    GROUP BY title
    ORDER BY MostUsers
```

You need to complete the query inserting the names of the fields that you can use to Join the tables

If you want all rooms you can use a Left Join:

```
    SELECT title, count(user) As MostUsers
    FROM Rooms R
    LEFT JOIN user_rooms U
    ON R.?field? = U.?field?
    GROUP BY title
    ORDER BY MostUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query:

select * from  rooms r 
order by  (select count(1)
         from userroom ur 
     where ur.roomid = r.roomid ) desc